# Keep program running after logging out SSH -X, and reopening it later

Tags: ssh, x11, nohup

I need to login to my school computer where I am running an experiment. I am logging via SSH -X since it uses a custom made GUI application. I want to be able open the program, make it start collection data, then logoff and check on it a few hours later.

I found many similar questions but but could not find a answer that would work for me. Screen and tmux are not available. Neither are byobu or similar stuff. The computer runs on some kind of old debian and I don't have root access.

I tried nohup which I understand should do the job but I could get it to work.
I did:

```
nohup myprogram &
exit
```

after I do `exit` the terminal doesn't close and the window of "myprogram" is still there. I have to close the terminal which asks me if I want to kill all open process.

I also couldn't find how to open a program that I have "nohuped" in a previous session. I tried doing `nohup myprogram &` again but it did not open the previous state of the program.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need root access to install new software - you can download the source code and compile it manually.

If you want to keep a program running after running and back to it, you could use `screen` or `tmux`. However, they are for command-line programs. For graphical programs, you may want to use [Xpra](http://xpra.org/).

Comment: Would anything be different if I already opened the program on the actual machine and just want to control it remotely?

Comment: @student You'd better run the program with Xpra first so you can return to it later, but if you already opened it, you'd have to use a tool like xmove or guievict(both of which are unmaintained).

Comment: Or you can use a remote control software like VNC(x11vnc lets you control a already-open X session remotely).